# When use Change Notification interface, the ORA-24912: Listener thread failed. Listen failed error occur?

Tags: oracle, notifications, otl

When I try to run the demo program to verify that the interface is right or not of Oracle Change Notification via `otl_subscriber` from the website:
http://otl.sourceforge.net/otl4_ex585.htm.

I got the errors as below:

> ORA-24912: Listener thread failed. Listen failed!

And after I search google, I got:"***The client needs to be restarted.***"
But I don't know **which client needs to be restarted**? The Oracle SQL Developer or any other clients?

I almost never revise the demo program, If I comment the segment as below:

```
//subs.subscribe();
//subs.subscribe();
```

the program works fine, and I can insert or drop tables.

From the beginning of the program, I learned that "The required 'change notification' privilege **can be set by "grant change notification to scott" by the DBA."**

Until now, I have no DBA privilege, Does the ORA-24912 bugs related with the 
DBA privilege?

Answer (score 0):

if you have installed then you might find some services pertaining to oracle. stop all service, start one by one again and check.

The client which the oracle is referring is a oracle db client supports to interfere with users through their dedicated protocols.

You will find even the client services under Services modules.

Comment: I already grant success， But I still got the errors as below:
"ORA-24912: Listener thread failed. Listen failed!".

Comment: # netstat -natpl | grep 10.20.1.5 
tcp        0      0 10.20.1.5:20035             10.20.1.5:1521              ESTABLISHED 6973/ora_pmon_ts54                                                                                  
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.20.1.5:1521       ::ffff:10.20.1.5:20035      ESTABLISHED 6871/tnslsnr        
tcp        0      0 ::ffff:10.20.1.5:1521       ::ffff:10.200.1.157:22025   ESTABLISHED 7043/oraclets54

Comment: Now I use ocilib resolved  the above bugs !http://orclib.sourceforge.net/doc/html/group___ocilib_c_api_subscriptions.html